# How to evaluate the quality of a solution obtained using the price-and-branch method for an IP problem?

Tags: integer-programming, column-generation, branch-and-price

I have solved an integer programming problem using the price-and-branch (not branch-and-price) approach exactly as same as described in [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/integer-column-generation-without-branch-price) and obtained a feasible solution. As this approach is heuristic, I would like to evaluate the quality of my solution or examine how far it is from the global optimum solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your problem is minimization, the step of solving the master LP yields a global lower bound, from which you can compute an optimality gap for your integer feasible solution.