Column generation for bin packing problem with variable size minimizing the largest cost of any class
I have a bin packing problem where the goal is to pack all items into bins with variable sizes where the bins are categorized as classes; the bins belongs to a class $m$, for example, have identical sizes. The shipping company charges based on classes; hence, the cost to be minimized $C$ is the largest class cost among the class costs. The cost of a class $m$, denoted by $C_m$, is the sum of the costs of the bins in that class. Each bin $b$ has a cost $C_b$, which is equal to the largest item cost in the bin, rather than the sum of the item costs.
\begin{align}
  x_{ib}
  &=
  \begin{cases}
  1,&\text{if item $i$ is packed into bin $b$}\\
  0,&\text{otherwise,}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&Min \quad C \\
\text{s.t} \hspace{5pt} \sum_{b}x_{ib} &= 1 &&\forall\ i \\
\sum_{i}w_ix_{ib} &\leq W_b &&\forall\ b \\
c_ix_{ib} &\leq C_b &&\forall\ i, b \\
\sum_{b \in m}C_b &\leq C && \forall\ m
\end{align}
Can I use the column generation for solving such a problem imposing the weight or capacity constraint into a subproblem and find a new column as finding a new bin contents??

Out of curiosity, what is the rational behind this cost definition?

@fontanf It is a type of promotion where you only pay for the maximum size of cargo you have, and the company covers any remaining costs.

Yes, you can.  Apply Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition to your compact formulation, with the second and third sets of constraints as your subproblem, which then decomposes into one block per bin $b$.

Thank you, Professor, for your answer. It was a great help. Regarding the subproblem, should I solve $M$ subproblems, one for each class (available capacity), and feed their solutions to the master problem, or should I solve one subproblem that incorporates all classes?

Both ways are correct, but I would expect better performance by splitting the subproblem into disjoint subproblems.

For the master problem, $C_b$ is a constant, not a variable.  Also, you should not explicitly impose $u_b \le 1$.  See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/608/variable-bounds-in-column-generation.  For your subproblem, the objective should be minimization, and you should have $C_b$ instead of $t_b$.

Yes I got it. A very helpful post. Thank you professor. I have read in one of your old answer that CG should produce optimal solutions. However I cannot reach that in some instances. I checked the values of $u_b$ in the last relaxed master problem has very small values and when I come to solve the IP master problem, the increase in the objval is large. Is that normal?

Are you solving the master IP problem just with columns that were generated during the master LP solve?

I add a large number of columns from the pricing problem and dont stop until no new good columns were found by the pricing problem. Then I solve the IP master problem. I only solve the LP master problem to get the dual values for the pricing problem.

That approach is only a heuristic.  See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/integer-column-generation-without-branch-price

Thank you, professor, I got it. Really appreciate it.
